# Swift: Difference between two CAAnimation Disables

Tags: swift, core-animation, catransaction

I am currently working with CABasic Animations on CALayers in Swift.

What is the difference between `CATransaction.setValue(kCFBooleanTrue, forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions)` and `CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From docs on [`.setDisableActions`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/catransaction/1448261-setdisableactions):

> This is a convenience method that invokes `setValue(_:forKey:)` with an **NSNumber** containing a **true** for the **kCATransactionDisableActions** key.

So, they basically do the same thing. Former is the [KVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/KeyValueCoding.html)-way of doing it.